# Load a VUE component with parameters

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have

```
<a role="button" v-on:click="setMemberName(item)">
```

And it calls a method:

```
 methods:{
    setMemberName(item) {           
        alert(item.email);
        this.$router.push('about');
    }
},
```

The alert gets fired and the router gets called but I need to send the parameter of item.email and I need to capture that when the 'about' vue gets loaded.  I have a simple alert being called using:

```
  ,
 mounted:function () {
    alert("Hello");
},
```

But I would like it to say "Hello " then the email address like "Hello Smith@jmail.com".  I really need the email address so I can call a webservice but Hello is fine for this problem. As you can tell VUE is new to me.

I have tried:

```
this.$router.push({ name: 'about', params: { itemEmail: item.email } })
```

but it seems that it never loads the 'about' vue.   Thanks for the help.

OK-- edit-- It does get fired if I use the proper case 'About' instead or 'about'  but I still need help on the capture side

Code for the about vue:  a simple div and some script code:

```
<script>
export default {
    name: 'About',
    data() {
        return {

        }
    },
    methods:{
    },
    mounted:function () {
    alert("Hello");
  },
    created(){
    },
  } 
</script>
```

Comment: please provide the code of  `about.vue`

Comment: Create a new component `<my-a>` or something and pass the value by `props` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways of solving this issue, your are using `route params` so you need to define the param in the route:

```
routes: [
  { path: '/about/:email', component: About }
]
```

Then you can access the param in the About component

In the template:

```
<div>Email: {{ $route.params.email }}</div>
```

In the script:

```
sayHello() {
  alert($route.params.email);
}
```

Note that you could also use `route query params` or `route props`, read the docs at: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/

Comment: This works for me but I was wondering can you send 2 or more parameter? and how would you set that up?  I didn't see that in the documentation.  Would you set it up as an array and parse it on the collection side?

Comment: You can send the data with `router query`, check @codenamev answer, nevertheless, you should consider using `Vuex` to store and share the global state of your app.

Answer (score 0):

If you update your `push` to ([see docs for full options](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#programmatic-navigation)):

```
 this.$router.push({ name: 'about', query: { itemEmail: item.email } })
```

You can access the query parameters ([See docs here](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#route-object-properties)):

```
this.$router.query.itemEmail
```